# Multiprocessing vs iterative approach

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am wondering why the iterative approach is faster in this implementation. Are the processes that are spawned doing too little work to benefit from the extra cores and hyper threads of my system? The iterative approach completes the called function in about 1/33 seconds. The multiprocessing approach does this in about 1/12 of a second.

```
import collections
import math
import random

from time import perf_counter
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

MULTIPROCESSING = True

MAX_PROCESSES = 24
CURRENT_PROCESSES = []
CURRENT_PROCESS_COUNT = len(CURRENT_PROCESSES)
PROCESSES_JOINED = 0
ITERATIONS_PERFORMED = 0
TRIALS = 10000

def count_bugs_needed(q):
    fragments = 0
    bugs_killed = 0
    drop_chance = .77

    while fragments < 41600:
        bugs_killed += 1
        if random.randint(1,100) >= int((1-drop_chance) * 100):
            fragments += 1
     
    if not MULTIPROCESSING:
        return bugs_killed
    else:
        q.put(bugs_killed)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_time = perf_counter()

    bug_count = []        
    
    if not MULTIPROCESSING:
        for x in range(TRIALS):    
            bug_count.append(count_bugs_needed(1))
            ITERATIONS_PERFORMED += 1
            if(ITERATIONS_PERFORMED % MAX_PROCESSES == 0):
                print(f"{ITERATIONS_PERFORMED=} SPEED={ITERATIONS_PERFORMED / (perf_counter() - start_time):.2f} ITERATIONS PER SECOND")
    
    else:
        q = Queue()
        for x in range(int(math.ceil(TRIALS/MAX_PROCESSES))):
            for _ in range(0, MAX_PROCESSES):
                CURRENT_PROCESSES.insert(0, Process(target=count_bugs_needed, args=(q,)))
                CURRENT_PROCESS_COUNT = len(CURRENT_PROCESSES)
                #print(f"{CURRENT_PROCESS_COUNT=}")
            for process in CURRENT_PROCESSES:
                process.start()
            for process in CURRENT_PROCESSES:
                bug_count.append(q.get())
            for _ in range(0, MAX_PROCESSES):
                process = CURRENT_PROCESSES.pop()
                process.join()      
                PROCESSES_JOINED += 1
                CURRENT_PROCESS_COUNT = len(CURRENT_PROCESSES)
                #print(f"{CURRENT_PROCESS_COUNT=}")
            q = Queue()
            print(f"{PROCESSES_JOINED=} SPEED={PROCESSES_JOINED / (perf_counter() - start_time):.2f} PROCESSES PER SECOND")
    
    exit()
    print("Done generating values. Starting to graph.")
        
    bug_count = sorted(bug_count)
    c = collections.Counter(bug_count)
    c = sorted(c.items())
    bug_count = [*set(bug_count)]
    freq = [i[1] for i in c]



    x_axis = bug_count
    y_axis = freq

    plt.scatter(x_axis, y_axis)
    plt.ylim(0, int(max(freq) * 1.2 + 1))
    plt.yticks(range(0, int(max(freq) * 1.2 + 1) + 1))
    plt.title('Frequency of bug kills for 41600 fragments')
    plt.xlabel('Bugs killed')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: It sounds like you're doing too little work overall. Multiprocessing starts up mutliple processes. If your action is finishing in 1/33 s, that is pretty quick. You're starting up 24 separate processes and communicating with them.

Comment: exactly as you have said and also as per @matt. The overhead for the start-up of multiprocess is greater than the benefit.  You would see advantages for bigger tasks (at some point). If you use the `dis` module, you would in fact find that the code has executed more tasks with multiprocessing !